# Retrieve Information using beautifulsoup difficulties

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to beautifulsoup, I would like to retrieve a specific element within th tag but the problem is that there are no way to identify the tags.

Below is the html elements

```html
<div class="tbl_racing_head" >
  <table class="tblgrey">
   <thead>
   <tr>
     <th width="65%" class="aln_left"><a name="1"></a>Race 1. THE ZILLAH CUP.<span class="pull-right"><a href="/index.php/en/racing/results?view=full#top" id="back-top">Back to Top</a></span></th>
     <th width="10%">1365 m</th>
     <th width="15%">Rating 25-0</th>
     <th width="10%">12h45</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
  </div>
```

I want to retrieve the th which has value 1365 but i can't find a way to get the value. I'm guessing that i have to use nextsibling or some parent method but I'm getting difficulties. Below is the code that I've tried

```html
url = 'http://www.mauritiusturfclub.com/index.php/en/racing/results? 
   meeting='+str(race_played)+'-'+str(2012)+'&view=full'
   source_code = requests.get(url)
   plain_text = source_code.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,'html.parser')
   print('Track '+soup.findAll('th',{'width':'10%'})[3])
```

I'm getting errors it doesn't seems to be working can someone explain me what is going on ? thanks

```html
<div class="tbl_racing_head" >
  <table class="tblgrey">
   <thead>
   <tr>
     <th width="65%" class="aln_left"><a name="1"></a>Race 1. THE ZILLAH CUP.<span class="pull-right"><a href="/index.php/en/racing/results?view=full#top" id="back-top">Back to Top</a></span></th>
     <th width="10%">1365 m</th>
     <th width="15%">Rating 25-0</th>
     <th width="10%">12h45</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
  </div>

  <table class="tblgrey">
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class="txt_center">Rank</th>
    <th class="txt_center">#</th>
    <th class="txt_center">Horse</th>
    <th class="txt_center">Stable</th>
    <th class="txt_center">Jockey</th>
    <th class="txt_center">Time</th>
        <th class="txt_center">Prize</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
     <td class="txt_center">1</td>
     <td class="txt_center">9</td>
     <td class="txt_left"><a  href="/index.php/en/component/mtc_horse_rating_list/?view=horse" >POLE OF COLD</a></td>
     <td class="txt_left">GUJADHUR</td>
     <td class="txt_left">V.Sola</td>
     <td class="txt_center">1m23.80</td>
          <td class="txt_center">115000</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
     <td class="txt_center">2</td>
     <td class="txt_center">8</td>
     <td class="txt_left"><a  href="/index.php/en/component/mtc_horse_rating_list/?view=horse" >ROMAN SPLENDOUR</a></td>
     <td class="txt_left">R.GUJADHUR</td>
     <td class="txt_left">J.Bardottier</td>
     <td class="txt_center">1m23.94</td>
          <td class="txt_center">38000</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
     <td class="txt_center">3</td>
     <td class="txt_center">6</td>
     <td class="txt_left"><a  href="/index.php/en/component/mtc_horse_rating_list/?view=horse" >ADDITION</a></td>
     <td class="txt_left">MAIGROT</td>
     <td class="txt_left">R.Hoolash</td>
     <td class="txt_center">1m24.18</td>
          <td class="txt_center">20000</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
     <td class="txt_center">4</td>
     <td class="txt_center">5</td>
     <td class="txt_left"><a  href="/index.php/en/component/mtc_horse_rating_list/?view=horse" >TANGERINE</a></td>
     <td class="txt_left">S.RAMDIN</td>
     <td class="txt_left">N.Marday</td>
     <td class="txt_center">1m24.68</td>
          <td class="txt_center">14000</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
     <td class="txt_center">5</td>
     <td class="txt_center">3</td>
     <td class="txt_left"><a  href="/index.php/en/component/mtc_horse_rating_list/?view=horse" >JUST OPPOSITE</a></td>
     <td class="txt_left">ALLET</td>
     <td class="txt_left">S.Bhundoo</td>
     <td class="txt_center">1m24.82</td>
          <td class="txt_center">8000</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
     <td class="txt_center">6</td>
     <td class="txt_center">10</td>
     <td class="txt_left"><a  href="/index.php/en/component/mtc_horse_rating_list/?view=horse" >PORT ALBERT</a></td>
     <td class="txt_left">C.RAMDIN</td>
     <td class="txt_left">S.Bussunt</td>
     <td class="txt_center">1m24.87</td>
          <td class="txt_center">0</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
     <td class="txt_center">7</td>
     <td class="txt_center">4</td>
     <td class="txt_left"><a  href="/index.php/en/component/mtc_horse_rating_list/?view=horse" >PACMAN</a></td>
     <td class="txt_left">S.HENRY</td>
     <td class="txt_left">B.Bhaugeerothee</td>
     <td class="txt_center">1m25.01</td>
          <td class="txt_center">0</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
     <td class="txt_center">8</td>
     <td class="txt_center">2</td>
     <td class="txt_left"><a  href="/index.php/en/component/mtc_horse_rating_list/?view=horse" >JUST MODERN</a></td>
     <td class="txt_left">G.ROUSSET</td>
     <td class="txt_left">N.Teeha</td>
     <td class="txt_center">1m25.38</td>
          <td class="txt_center">0</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
     <td class="txt_center">9</td>
     <td class="txt_center">1</td>
     <td class="txt_left"><a  href="/index.php/en/component/mtc_horse_rating_list/?view=horse" >DREAMS COME TRUE</a></td>
     <td class="txt_left">R.MAINGARD</td>
     <td class="txt_left">K.Ghunowa</td>
     <td class="txt_center">1m25.52</td>
          <td class="txt_center">0</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
     <td class="txt_center">-</td>
     <td class="txt_center">7</td>
     <td class="txt_left"><a  href="/index.php/en/component/mtc_horse_rating_list/?view=horse" >CARAMEL KING</a></td>
     <td class="txt_left">P.MERVEN</td>
     <td class="txt_left">S.Rama</td>
     <td class="txt_center">-</td>
          <td class="txt_center">0</td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
s = """<div class="tbl_racing_head" >
        <table class="tblgrey">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="65%" class="aln_left"><a name="1"></a>Race 1. THE ZILLAH CUP.<span class="pull-right"><a href="/index.php/en/racing/results?view=full#top" id="back-top">Back to Top</a></span></th>
              <th width="10%">1365 m</th>
              <th width="15%">Rating 25-0</th>
              <th width="10%">12h45</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        </div>"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')
for tr in soup.findAll("tr"):
    print(tr.find("th", {'width':'10%'}).text)
```

Comment: The code you provide works perfectly erm but if I have multiple tables containing different values of "distance"(the th mention)  how can I get the values of the next th? see post above I've added the html code

Comment: Sorry i do not understand. Cam you show expected output?